# Connect to another database in SQL Server instance from within 'Safe' CLR database trigger

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlclr

I am writing a CLR Update trigger for SQL Server 2008 R2. The trigger needs to write updated values to a table in another database hosted in the same SQL Server instance. When I try to open a connection created with the following connection string from within my trigger I get a "SecurityException":

> ...new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=[my database];Integrated Security=True")

It is highly desirable that I leave my assembly's permission level as `SAFE`. I am pretty sure that I'd have to set my assembly's permission level to `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` to connect to a remote database, but is it possible to connect to another database in the same SQL Server instance with the `SAFE` permission level?

Thanks.

Comment: It's almost always better to defer cross-database (or cross-server) activity until *after* the trigger has fired. You don't usually want the unavailability of the second database (or any other external resource) to prevent the original transaction from completing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is definitely possible to reference another database in a SQLCLR trigger that resides inside of an Assembly marked as `SAFE`. The error encountered in the question is due simply to using a regular / external connection string, which requires a `PERMISSION_SET` of `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`. But using the in-process / internal connection string of `"Context Connection = true;"` allows you to run whatever query you want, including a query that references another database via 3-part object name.

I was able to do this with the following code:

**Main Table (in TestDB1):**

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Stuff
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Something] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

**Audit Table (in TestDB2):**

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.AuditLog
(
    AuditLogID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    EventTime DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
    BeforeValue NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    AfterValue NVARCHAR(50) NULL
);
```

**SQLCLR Trigger on main table (partial code):**

```cs
string _AuditSQL = @"
    INSERT INTO TestDB2.dbo.AuditLog (BeforeValue, AfterValue)
        SELECT del.Something, ins.Something
        FROM   INSERTED ins
        FULL OUTER JOIN DELETED del
                     ON del.Id = ins.Id;
";

SqlConnection _Connection = new SqlConnection("Context Connection = true");
SqlCommand _Command = _Connection.CreateCommand();
_Command.CommandText = _AuditSQL;

try
{
    _Connection.Open();
    _Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
finally
{
    _Command.Dispose();
    _Connection.Dispose();
}
```

**Test queries:**

```sql
USE [TestDB1];
SELECT * FROM dbo.Stuff;
---
INSERT INTO dbo.Stuff (Something) VALUES ('qwerty');
INSERT INTO dbo.Stuff (Something) VALUES ('asdf');

SELECT * FROM dbo.Stuff;
SELECT * FROM TestDB2.dbo.AuditLog;
---
UPDATE  tab
SET     tab.Something = 'dfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgd'
FROM    dbo.Stuff tab
WHERE   tab.Id = 2;

SELECT * FROM dbo.Stuff;
SELECT * FROM TestDB2.dbo.AuditLog;
```

Comment: @bdebaere I also just noticed that you asked a collation / encoding question that wasn't tagged as collation...I will answer that one...

Comment: @bdebaere Sounds good. Accepted (as I'm sure you saw).  Also, if this answer helped you, please don't forget to upvote :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not possible. However a T-SQL statement can reference another database in the same instance by using [DatabaseName].[dbo].[TableName]. I can do the messy logic in my CLR trigger, then do a final insert into the second database by calling a simple T-SQL stored procedure and passing in parameters.

Comment: Andrew, this is possible. Please see my answer for details.